# set versus select query decimal place

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, set

```
DECLARE @TotalRunBalance decimal
```

Query

```
SELECT SUM (RunBalance) AS WhatShows from Activity_Table where Engine#=1
```

Answer obtained: 2.49

Query

```
SET @TotalRunBalance = (SELECT SUM(RunBalance) from Activity_Table where Engine#=1)
SELECT @TotalRunBalance AS WhatShows2
```

Answer Displayed: 2

Anyone got any answers why I'm losing the 0.49? - its wrecking the next calculations, when I'm using the @TotalRunBalance variable

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add precision `DECIMAL(m,a)`

```
Example 
declare @TotalRunBalance decimal(18,3)

set @TotalRunBalance=2.49
select @TotalRunBalance
```

your case below

```
DECLARE @TotalRunBalance decimal(18,3) // add precision in decimal declaratiton


Query
SELECT SUM (RunBalance) AS WhatShows from Activity_Table where Engine#=1
Answer obtained: 2.49

Query
SET @TotalRunBalance = (SELECT SUM(RunBalance) from Activity_Table where Engine#=1)
SELECT @TotalRunBalance AS WhatShows2
```

Comment: This has fixed the problem. Thank you for assisting so quickly. Many Thanks.

Comment: @DBurdett if it helps accept it as a answer SO  appreciation